# How to archive a UItextfield whose text color is gradient?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, gradient

I am trying to archive a textfield.where the text field text is a gradient color.I archive it to store data into my Core database.But the archive method is giving my this error. `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only RGBA or White color spaces are supported in this situation.'` The archive code is `let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: testerText)` . the `viewdidload` code is.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       testerText.textColor = UIColor(patternImage: gradientImage(size: testerText.frame.size, color1: CIColor(color: UIColor.green), color2: CIColor(color: UIColor.red), direction: .Left))

        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: testerText)

        //print(toshow)

    }
```

and the function which make the text color gradient is given below.

```
func gradientImage(size: CGSize, color1: CIColor, color2: CIColor, direction: GradiantDerection = .Up) -> UIImage {

    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CILinearGradient")
    var startVector: CIVector
    var endVector: CIVector

    filter!.setDefaults()

    switch direction {
    case .Up:
        startVector = CIVector(x: size.width * 0.5, y: 0)
        endVector = CIVector(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height)
    case .Left:
        startVector = CIVector(x: size.width, y: size.height * 0.5)
        endVector = CIVector(x: 0, y: size.height * 0.5)
    case .UpLeft:
        startVector = CIVector(x: size.width, y: 0)
        endVector = CIVector(x: 0, y: size.height)
    case .UpRight:
        startVector = CIVector(x: 0, y: 0)
        endVector = CIVector(x: size.width, y: size.height)
    }

    filter!.setValue(startVector, forKey: "inputPoint0")
    filter!.setValue(endVector, forKey: "inputPoint1")
    filter!.setValue(color1, forKey: "inputColor0")
    filter!.setValue(color2, forKey: "inputColor1")

    let image = UIImage(cgImage: context.createCGImage(filter!.outputImage!, from: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))!)
    return image
}
```

Now I want to know how do I archive those `textfield` so that I can store it to my database?

Comment: Instead of archiving the textfield, you could just archive the text?

Comment: I also think so.but I need the same gradient color.Now you can say me also save the gradient color.But it's an existing project where many user use it and they have there data already in there mobile database.the previous version only have text tin color.but this time we need to give gradient.hope you undrestand @Flexicoder.

Comment: @Rumy Convert the UIImage `func gradientImage ` to NSData, save it to your storage, retrieve it, use it.

Comment: @Rumy Your gradient is essentially just a pattern of an image you are creating. I don't understand why would that cause problems with already existing Database schema, you are merely adding a new column of NSData type. Your image is not a color!

Comment: @NSNoob do you want to say to store text and gradient image as NSData into different field and when reload them back we should marge them using same method???

Comment: Archiving a view into your model is a very unusual and strange requirement. Generally views are created when the app runs, based on saved data. Saving the actual view doesn't make sense in many cases.

Answer (score -1):

**Try This One For GradientText in TextField**

```
      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
      testerText.textColor = UIColor(patternImage: gradientImage(size: testerText.frame.size, color1: CIColor(color: UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)), color2: CIColor(color: UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.2))))

      let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: testerText.text as Any)
      }



   func gradientImage(size: CGSize, color1: CIColor, color2: CIColor) -> UIImage {

       let context = CIContext(options: nil)
       let filter = CIFilter(name: "CILinearGradient")
       var startVector: CIVector
       var endVector: CIVector

      filter!.setDefaults()

      startVector = CIVector(x: size.width * 0.5, y: 0)
      endVector = CIVector(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 0.8)

          filter!.setValue(startVector, forKey: "inputPoint0")
          filter!.setValue(endVector, forKey: "inputPoint1")
          filter!.setValue(color1, forKey: "inputColor0")
          filter!.setValue(color2, forKey: "inputColor1")

      let image = UIImage(cgImage: 
      context.createCGImage(filter!.outputImage!, from: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))!)
         return image

        }
```

Comment: this does not answer the question about *archiving*.

Comment: Now Just try it. we have to just show the gradient text but we can get the text only not the colour.

Comment: I guess archiving everything is what OP is after.